# How to configure Doctrine for MongoDB master/slave replica to automatically failover

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have two MongoDB instances - one slave and one master. There is an Arbiter too.

Basically the setup is the following:
[image]
(*Image Source: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/replication/*)

In my Symfony application, in config.yml I have this for MongoDB:

```
# Mongo DB
doctrine_mongodb:
connections:
    default:
        server: %database_mongodb_access%
        options: {}
default_database: %database_mongodb_name%
document_managers:
    default:
        auto_mapping: true
```

where `%database_mongodb_access%` is `'mongodb://mongo:27017'`.

How to configure my Symfony/Doctrine application to automatically failover to the slave MongoDB instance if the primary fails, so the application continues working?

It is not clear to me from the docs:
http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/DoctrineMongoDBBundle/config.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to connect to several mongodb servers on one connection if you are using a replica set by listing all of the servers within the connection string as a comma separated list.

```
doctrine_mongodb:
    # ...
    connections:
        default:
            server: "mongodb://mongodb-01:27017,mongodb-02:27017,mongodb-03:27017"
```

http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/DoctrineMongoDBBundle/config.html#connecting-to-a-pool-of-mongodb-servers-on-1-connection

And check the retry mechanism for failover :

http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/DoctrineMongoDBBundle/config.html#retrying-connections-and-queries

Comment: Now my applicaiton fails over, but somehow the secondary DB does not become the master `CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception MongoWriteConcernException: "X.X.X.X: not master"....`. However this is a different problem that my by related to arbiter or something else. But your answer helped, thanks.

Comment: @Pixel1002 I think you should not list arbiter address as value for 'server' key. Because arbiter is only used as helper instance for decision making about primary and secondary voting